# VSTS - Automatically link new work in this build is not working

Tags: azure-devops

In Project A, I setup a build to automatically link the build to associated workitems...worked flawless the first time.

In another project - I have a build-definition which does not set the link.

What's curious - a *clone* of said definition, with some tasks removed (basically just "Upload Artifacts" removed, cause it is just a build-verification test for pull-requests) *does* set the link.

I even re-created the build-definition from scratch, still no links added *sigh*

Anybody have any insights on these problems?

Also - I ran the build in "debug" mode, with detailed logs...could not find any information which would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Johannes Colmsee

Update: there is another task I removed from the "Build-Verification" Build-definition: publish symbols

Update 2: for brand new build-definitions, I will get a warning telling me that the link was *not* created because too many changesets were associated…for subsequent builds though...no warning, but also no link *sigh*

Update 3: also - I can manually select the builds for "integrated in build" link in the workitem - so...they could potentially be added automatically too I suppose...

Update 4: the subsequent PullRequest and the following builds all associated OK to the workitems….so it was probably my fault.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message in your Update 2 should be the reason. "Automatically link work" feature compares the changes and work items between the current build and previous build. When the count of changes or work items is more than 200, it will not link. When you create a new build definition and run a build, there is no previous build which means that all the changes and work items in your code repository are calculated. And also if there is no change or no work item linked in the change in the subsequent build, it will not link any work either.