# Why are work Items linked to multiple builds in the same build pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are getting cases where our Work Items are getting included in many builds and [without sufficient documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6597) I can't seem to work out why. Wondered if anyone here could shine any light on this.

Example scenario is

- We run "Release Flow" branch strategy (like MS describe they do for Azure DevOps)
- Bug 30368 was linked to a feature branch and got back into master via PR 2991 and commit cb9120d0.
- All the appropriate links to PR and Branch were in place for this so both the PR and the master commit show the link to the work item correctly
- We create our release branch off of master and 30368 was included in v2.97.0 build pipeline and was linked (correctly) with an "integrated in build" to that build
- Build 1 is created
- We then had a bug in v2.97.0 during release testing (not to do with Bug 20368) and so we Cherry Picked the master commit with the fix into the release branch (as per Release Flow guidance).
- **I'm wondering that this Cherry Pick is the cause of the problem I describe later**
- Of course the work item wasn't included in this second build of v2.97.0, only the work item with the related fix was
- Build 2 is created
- So all is good so far. v2.97.0 release is deployed from Build 2 and all the links are correct
- Now we branch from master for v2.98 release and the release pipeline does another build.

  - Build 3
- For some reason it determines that 30368 should be linked to this build also and adds a "integrated in build" to the v2.98 build?

The only other clue that I've found is to do with the commits that are linked with the build. Here I can see that I get the following

- Build 1

  - from e0faff8f (master 2019-12-02 commit release 2.97 was branched from )
  - to db225f14 (from feature branch just before PR completed 2019-11-21)
- Build 2

  - from aeaf3dc5 (release branch 2019-12-03 cherry picked)
  - to e0faff8f (pull request branch 2019-12-03)
- Build 3

  - from f2ce6d3d (release branch 2019-12-06)
  - to f3db8c7b (2019-12-02)

It isn't even clear to me how the build pipeline knows what the range of git commits are included in it and perhaps this is the key to understanding the link. Of course it gets the From part from the commit that the build ran from but how does it know which commit it should go to?

Also in the above example, neither the range given for Build 1 or Build 3 seems to have the commit that is related to the item (cb9120d0) in it - even though this work item has been linked to these builds?

It is all pretty confusing and nebulous.

Has anyone got this feature working correctly/reliably?

I also wondered if we need to create specific pipelines for each branch so that each branch is independent but I'm not sure as even if you create a brand new pipeline and point it to the master branch it doesn't include every single commit ever (and workitem) in that build. Again, how does it know where to start?

Comment: Maybe you can get some hint about how this feature works from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52888197/10910450).

Comment: Thanks but the two issues are quite different. In mine, incorrect PBIs are getting linked, in the article you sent none are getting linked and he was getting a warning. 

I don't understand why an item would be linked multiple times for the same pipeline in subsequent builds. There is very little documentation that I can find about how this should work.

Comment: Hi Brett, sorry but I can't reproduce same issue in my machine so far. Is the Bug 30368 and 20368 the same one?

Comment: yes, sorry this is a typo. they are the same. I've fixed it in the OP

Comment: Hi, does this issue can be reproduced in a new project with simple steps? It's hard to reproduce the same issue for better trouble-shooting on my side, maybe you can check if this issue only occurs in current project to determine if the issue results from the cherry pick...

Comment: Ok, if this isn't a known/commin problem, I will try. It would be useful to have some idea on how this is supposed to work as then I might be able to understand what is going on. It is very opaque right now so I am just having to guess which is frustrating and time consuming

Comment: For `even though this work item has been linked to these builds`, the commits of work item just represents the actual code work which relevant with work item. The commits of work item does not has direct relationship with builds even you link the wit with builds. The commits of build are only detected from the source repos operation history.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that builds are somehow not using the work item to git commit? "The commits of build are only detected from the source repos operation history." how can it do this if it isn't using the connection of work item to source commit?

Comment: For example, i have some changes to files in one branch between its first build and lastest build, the latest build will automatically fetch the latest commits from devops repos, this process has no direct relationship with wit...